# ImageStream Source

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, nullreferenceexception

I have a picture  `String myimg = "images.jpg";`  and I want to set like a `ImageStream` to `mediaHistoryItem`

I tried this code:

```
if (mediaHistoryItem.ImageStream == null)
{
    StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("real.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    Stream stream = sri.Stream;
    mediaHistoryItem.ImageStream = stream;
}
```

but it give me exception `NullreferenceException`.

Comment: Well, something is null. Did you check which line is giving you the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure your picture: real.jpg 's properties:build action is "content" And FilePath is right.

If your image's build action is "resource" you should use path: [projectName];component/real.jpg

Comment: Read here http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action

Comment: it worck now thunk you very Much (Merci Bouceaup)